# Issue with Trulens Evaluation and TruChain(using LangChain)

Tags: azure, langchain, large-language-model

I'm currently working on LLM evaluation using Trulens and Azure openAi and encountering some issues with the code. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
 retriever = vectorstore .as_retriever()

prompt = hub.pull("rlm/rag-prompt")

def format_docs(docs):
    return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)

rag_chain = (
    {"context": retriever | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)
```

When attempting to apply the Trulens recorder with the following code:

```
# TruLens Eval chain recorder
chain_recorder = TruChain(
    rag_chain, app_id="Chain1_ChatApplication", feedbacks=[f_qa_relevance, f_context_relevance, f_groundedness])
```

I encounter the error:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for TruChain
app
  Can't instantiate abstract class Chain with abstract methods _call, input_keys, output_keys (type=type_error)
```

I also tried applying TruChain with an llm Langchain chain:

```
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever()
)
chain_recorder = TruChain(
    qa, app_id="contextual-chatbot", feedbacks=[f_qa_relevance, f_context_relevance, f_groundedness]
)
```

However, this results in the error:(in the chain_recorder part)

```
TypeError: Object of type 'OpenAI' is not JSON serializable
```

I'm using Python 3.10.11 and have also tested with Python 3.9. The relevant package versions are as follows:

```
langchain==0.1.0
langchain-community==0.0.9
langchain-core==0.1.7
langchainhub==0.1.14
trulens-eval==0.18.1
```